# How to make Fabric continue running the next command after getting the exit status: 1?

Tags: python, fabric, exitstatus

I'm going to install [check_mk](http://mathias-kettner.de/check_mk.html) plugin by writing a simple fabfile like this:

```python
from fabric.api import env, run, roles, execute, parallel

env.roledefs = {
    'monitoring': ['192.168.3.118'],
    'mk-agent': ['192.168.3.230', '192.168.3.231', '192.168.3.232']
}

@roles('monitoring')
def mk():
    run('[ -f check_mk-1.1.12p7.tar.gz ] || wget http://mathias-kettner.de/download/check_mk-1.1.12p7.tar.gz')
    run('[ -d check_mk-1.1.12p7 ] || tar zxvf check_mk-1.1.12p7.tar.gz')
    run('cd check_mk-1.1.12p7 && sudo ./setup.sh')

@parallel    
@roles('mk-agent')
def mk_agent():
    run('[ `rpm -qa | grep -c xinetd` -eq 0 ] && sudo yum -y install xinetd.x86_64')
    run('sudo rpm -ivh http://mathias-kettner.de/download/check_mk-agent-1.2.0b2-1.noarch.rpm') 

def check_mk():
    execute(mk)
    execute(mk_agent)
```

But, as you can guess, if the `xinetd` package is already installed, Fabric will be stopped with below errors:

```
Fatal error: run() received nonzero return code 1 while executing!

Requested: [ `rpm -qa | grep -c xinetd` -eq 0 ] && sudo yum -y install xinetd.x86_64
Executed: /bin/bash -l -c "[ \`rpm -qa | grep -c xinetd\` -eq 0 ] && sudo yum -y install xinetd.x86_64"

Aborting.
```

Is there any solution in this situation?

Answer (score 21):

since stackoverflow doesn't let me upvote Morgan's answer without more rep, I'll contribute more detail from http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.1/api/core/context_managers.html#fabric.context_managers.settings

Outside the 'with settings' in the code below, behaviour will return to normal :

```
def my_task():
    with settings(
        hide('warnings', 'running', 'stdout', 'stderr'),
        warn_only=True
    ):
        if run('ls /etc/lsb-release'):
            return 'Ubuntu'
        elif run('ls /etc/redhat-release'):
            return 'RedHat'
```

This is desirable since you can essentially 'catch' what would've been an error in one section without it being fatal, but leave errors fatal elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps in 2020 it will be useful.
In Fabric 2.5, you just need to add the `warn=True` to the command to avoid interruption.

For example: `connection.run('test -f /path/to/file && tail /path/to/file, warn=True)`

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to add "env.warn_only = True" to the def mk_agent(): task.

Answer (score 0):

[**Fabric Failure handling**](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.1/usage/execution.html#failure-handling)

Once the task list has been constructed, Fabric will start executing them as outlined in [Execution strategy](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.1/usage/execution.html#execution-strategy), until all tasks have been run on the entirety of their host lists. However, Fabric defaults to a **“fail-fast”** behavior pattern: *if anything goes wrong, such as a remote program returning a nonzero return value or your fabfile’s Python code encountering an exception, execution will halt immediately.*

This is typically the desired behavior, but there are many exceptions to the rule, so Fabric provides `env.warn_only`, a Boolean setting. It defaults to `False`, meaning an error condition will result in the program aborting immediately. However, if `env.warn_only` is set to `True` at the time of failure – with, say, the [settings](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.1/api/core/context_managers.html#fabric.context_managers.settings) context manager – Fabric will emit a warning message but continue executing.

```
def my_task():
    with settings(
        hide('warnings', 'running', 'stdout', 'stderr'),
        warn_only=True
    ):
        if run('ls /etc/lsb-release'):
            return 'Ubuntu'
        elif run('ls /etc/redhat-release'):
            return 'RedHat'
```